# Stable curve local complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a [stable curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_curve#Definition) over base field $k$. How to show that $C$ is [*local complete intersection*](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00S8) purely algebraically?

I'm emphasizing pure algebraically here because the only proof of this statement familar to me is from [Geometry of Algebraic Curves Volume II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69392-5) ( page 86) where are used GAGA techniques to transfer this from analytic ( where it is immediate) to algebraic case. And I'm wondering if it isn's really possible to argue direct by algebraic methods.

Can it be generalited to more general affine Noetherian base scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, you can first embed the curve into some projective space and then choose a general projection to a plane. If the center of the projection does not lie in the plane spanned by the tangent lines to the components of the curve at the nodes, nor on a secant line to the curve passing through a node, then the projection gives an isomorphism of neighborhoods of the nodes onto some curve in the plane, and any curve in the plane is a local complete intersection.

Comment: but does't such center of projection $L^{n-3} \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-3} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ with required properties in your answer exist for  *every* embedded curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$, not specifically the stable ones? Just pick any linear subspace  $L^{n-3} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ containing a point not lying on any of these tangent lines associated to the nodes.

Comment: Or do you possibly mean as distinguishing condition for the choice of the center of projection $L^{n−3} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
 instead that it *not* contains any of such finitely many tangent lines assoc to the nodes? In our case above just consider as the finite collection of tangents (more general $m$- tuples for $m$-fold points) the pairs of tangents coming from the nodes. So, if I not missing something we can extend the arguement to $m$- fold points, right?

Comment: The argument works for any nodal curve, stability is irrelevant. As for curves with $m$-fold points, it depends on what do you mean by that. For instance, you can glue three lines in a point in such a way that the Zariski tangent space at that point is 2-dimensional, then the curve is lci, or 3-dimensional, then it is not.

Comment: The condition on the center of projection is not sufficient. First, it should not be in the same plane as the tangent lines at any node. Next, the line from the center to any node should not meet the curve anywhere else.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: Thanks! Of course you are right. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: For sake of curiosity, do you know if there also exist an "intrinsic" argument without making concrete choices ( like in situation above using a concrete embedding, centers of projection, etc.)? I'm wondering about this because for local rings (ie after passing to stalks) the property "being lci" is so far I know an intrinsic property - depending only on the local ring itself, not the "enviroment" , so it suggests, that if we consider it "local enough" it's reasonble to expect existence of a way to see it without involved choices. Do you know one such approach?

Comment: Usually there is no canonical representation of an lci variety as a local complete intersection in a smooth variety, so some choices are usually unavoidable. In the case of a nodal curve, for each node $P \in C$ you can take the generators of $\mathfrak{m}_P/\mathfrak{m}_P^2 \cong k^2$, lift them to $\mathfrak{m}_P$ (a choice!), and obtain a surjective homomorpishm $k[x,y] \to \mathcal{O}_{C,P}$. This also proves that a neighborhood of $P$ in $C$ is isomorphic to a plane curve.